# Como posso excluir o penultimo número de um periodo?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou tentando deixar o período de 201601 para 20161 no SQL, mas não consigo de jeito algum!

Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(5), CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(Periodo_Mensal))+ 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), MONTH(Periodo_Mensal))) AS PERIODO_MENSAL
```

Tentei o `LEN`, tentei o `REPLACE`, mas nada da certo.

Comment: select left('201601', 4) + right('201601', 1)

Comment: Onde eu encaixo esse select?

Comment: Editei minha resposta

Comment: @tcm, qual é o sgbd? Existem funções que facilitam conversão de datas, mas que variam de sgbd para sgbd.

Comment: SQLServer é o SGBD

Answer (score 2):

[MONTH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187813.aspx) vai retornar um inteiro, assim sendo na conversão o `0` a esquerda irá sumir.

```
declare @hoje datetime,
        @periodo varchar(6);

set @hoje = '2016-01-01';

-- Pega o ano + o mês
set @periodo = cast(year(@hoje) as varchar) + cast(month(@hoje) as varchar);

select @periodo as periodo_mensal;
```

Comment: Onde eu encaixo o select?

Answer (score 2):

Para converter uma data para aaaamm, formato numérico, há algumas formas.

```
-- código #1
SELECT (YEAR(Periodo_Mensal) * 100 + 
        MONTH(Periodo_Mensal)) as PERIODO_MENSAL
  from ...
```

Se necessita que o resultado seja *string*, pode-se ter

```
-- código #2
SELECT Convert(char(6), (YEAR(Periodo_Mensal) * 100 + 
                         MONTH(Periodo_Mensal))
              ) as PERIODO_MENSAL
      from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Se seu objetivo for remover sempre o 0 a esquerda, basta usar o [DAY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms176052.aspx), ele retorna um `int` do valor passado, como o int sempre iguinora o 0 a esquerda você terá removido ele por default.

```
declare @hoje datetime = '20160101';
select cast(year(@hoje) as varchar) + cast(month(@hoje) as varchar) 
+ cast(day(@hoje) as varchar)
```

Ou conforme o comentário abaixo (Ele só quer o ano e o mês – Sorack 1 min atrás),  o [month()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187813.aspx), também tem a mesma função do DAY.

```
declare @hoje datetime = '20160101';
select cast(year(@hoje) as varchar) + cast(month(@hoje) as varchar)
```